# How to get index of UI?

Tags: applescript

I want to get index of UI. I did like following, but I couldn't. Is there any way?

**source:**

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        index of button 9 of scroll area 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

**result:**

```
error
```

**expected result:**

```
9
```

Comment: What application are you targeting?

Comment: @adayzdone: "System Preferences". But I think it doesn't need to specify application to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AS System Events UI Elements Suite does not contain a property like id or index for UI Elements. The call

```
button 9 of scroll area 1 of window 1
```

just targets the ninth button, not the button with `id 9`. You could also write

```
ninth button of scroll area 1 of window 1
```

The only way I can think of something returning the 9 would be to walk through all buttons with a repeat loop:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        repeat with ix from 1 to count (buttons of scroll area 1 of window 1)
            if name of button ix of scroll area 1 of window 1 = "Monitors" then
                return ix
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

The result is 9 then.

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg